# screen capture really wide webpage

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-visualization

I have just been using some of the Google charting tools to help me with the development of some threaded code, and I have an output like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8BtsLXcNIF3Z3BaWENoNVYxOUk/edit?usp=sharing)

if you look at the file in Chrome you will see a pretty but very large Gantt chart.

My problem is that I cannot save this as anything (pdf/image) or print it as it is too wide.  I have tried the Google screen capture, save to Google drive and PDF save plugins for chrome and printing directly confines me to the width of 1 page of A4.

Anyone know how I could go about printing/saving these large webpages?

Comment: Is this a programming question? And why not save it as html? (ctrl+s)

Comment: It is already an HTML page, but I want to print it out, or include it in a presentation or something like that.

The problem is that it is 10000 pixels wide

Comment: You could try using the canvg library to convert the SVG to Canvas, and then save the canvas as a .png file.  There's example code demonstrating this here: http://jsfiddle.net/SCjm8/1/.  It works reasonably well in Chrome and occasionally in Firefox.  It does not work at all in IE.  If all you need is to create an image for personal use, this is fine, but I would avoid using it on a production website.

Comment: Thanks asgallant, not what I asked for, but exactly what I needed.  Thats now implemented and I can capture some lovely images from a nice button in the page.  Great answer

Comment: So after the great comment from asgallant I modified my [code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8BtsLXcNIF3dURXbTdpOXlWMUk/edit?usp=sharing)

This then gives a button at the top of the page which uses canvg to save the image, as shown [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8BtsLXcNIF3QjV0WUlGU0hTaEU/edit?usp=sharing), this is 10000x2000 pixels in size, and perfect for what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after the great comment from asgallant I modified my [code](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8BtsLXcNIF3dURXbTdpOXlWMUk/edit). This then gives a button at the top of the page which uses canvg to save the image, as shown [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8BtsLXcNIF3QjV0WUlGU0hTaEU/edit), this is 10000x2000 pixels in size, and perfect for what I need.

Its not exactly the answer to this question in general, but it works perfectly for my problem.